# Insertar datos en formulario con clave foraneas laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

necesito ayuda, tengo problemas para crear un nuevo registro o actualizarlo, desde un formulario, ya que utilizo claves foraneas para hacerlo.
El error es

```
"Undefined variable: marcas (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\.....
```

estos son mis scripts

Modelos

```
class Marca extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'marcas';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
    ];

} 

class Vehiculo extends Model
{
        protected $table = 'vehiculos';
        protected $fillable = [
            'matricula', 'marca', 'modelo', 'capacidad_carga', 'año_fabricacion', 'color', 'estado',
        ];
    ......
    public function relMarca()
            {   
                return $this->BelongsTo('Marca');


            }

    }
```

Ruta

```
Route::post('nuevo/{id?}', 'VehiculoController@agregar_nuevo_vehiculo');
```

Controlador

Funcion  para crear

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use App\Vehiculo;
use App\Marca;
...

public function agregar_nuevo_vehiculo()
    {
        $marcas=Marca();
        $data = Request::all();

       $vehiculo=new Vehiculo;
       $vehiculo->matricula=$data['matricula'];   
       $vehiculo->marca=$data['$marcas'];
       $vehiculo->modelo=$data['modelo'];
       $vehiculo->capacidad_carga=$data['capacidad_carga'];
       $vehiculo->año_fabricacion=$data['año_fabricacion'];
       $vehiculo->color=$data['color'];
       $vehiculo->estado=$data['estado'];

       $resul = $vehiculo->save();
       if ($resul){

           return view ('mensajes.msj_correcto')->with('msj','Nuevo vehiculo incorporado exitosamente');
       }
       else
           return view ('mensajes.msj_rechazado')->with('msj','Hubo un error en al creacion del vehiculo, vuelva a intentarlo, por favor');

    }
```

formulario

```
                 <<form  id="f_nuevo_vehiculo"  method="post"  action="agregar_nuevo_vehiculo" class="form-horizontal form_entrada" > {{ csrf_field() }}               
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">              

                    <div id="f_nuevo_vehiculo"class="box-body col-xs-12">
                        <div  class="row col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                  <label id="modal_elem" for="matricula">Matricula</label>
                                  <input id="modal_elem" type="text" class="form-control" id="matricula" name="matricula" p required placeholder="Introducir matricula" >
                            </div>


                            <div  class="form-group col-xs-4">
                            <label id="modal_elem" for="marca">Marca</label>

                                <select id="marca" name="marca" class="form-control">

                                @foreach($marcas as $mark)
                <option value="$mark->marcas->id"> {{'$mark->marcas->nombre' }} </option>
 @endforeach  

                                </select>

                            </div>

                            <div  class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                  <label id="modal_elem" for="modelo">Modelo</label>
                                  <input id="modal_elem" type="text" class="form-control" id="modelo" name="modelo" placeholder="Introducir modelo" >
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class=row col-xs-12>
                            <div  class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                <label id="modal_elem" for="capacidad_carga">Capacidad</label>
                                <input id="modal_elem" type="number" class="form-control" id="capacidad_carga" name="capacidad_carga" placeholder="Capacidad Tons" >
                            </div>

                            <div  class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                <label id="modal_elem" for="año_fabricacion">Año de Fabricación</label>
                                <input id="modal_elem" type="date" class="form-control" id="año_fabricacion" name="año_fabricacion"  placeholder="Seleccionar" >
                            </div>

                            <div  class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                <label id="modal_elem" for="color">Color</label>
                                <input id="modal_elem" type="text" class="form-control" id="color" name="color" placeholder="Introducir color" >


                            </div>
                        <div class=row col-xs-12>
                            <div  class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                <label id="modal_elem" for="estado">Estado</label>
                                <select id="estado" name="estado" class="form-control">

                               <option value="1">Disponible</option>
                               <option value="2">En mantenimiento</option>
                                <option value="3">No disponible</option>

                                  </select>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                         </div>

                            <div class="box-footer col-xs-12 ">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                            </div>




                     </div>



              </div>

               <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline">Save changes</button>

               </div>

               </div> 
           </form>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tu ruta POST tiene esto {id?}? Route::post('nuevo/{id?}

Comment: Hola Alexis queria pasar como parametro el id para que me identificara mejor el registro

Comment: La ruta POST no debería tener ID si es que tu ID es incremental, ¿No estás trabajando con --resource Controller?

Comment: @AlexiGallegosPerez creo que tu pregunta debería haber sido un comentario. Para la próxima tenelo en cuenta porque en esta comunidad son demasiado estrictos en sus normas y realmente tu pregunta no es una respuesta. Yo te lo comento nomás, hay algunos usuarios de esta comunidad que pueden llegar a ser un tanto agresivos con sus "comentarios" y hacerte sentir no muy bienvenido.

Comment: Ahora respondiendo a tu pregunta, cuando el parámetro tiene un signo de interrogación esto significa que es OPCIONAL. Pero como bien decis en tu ultimo comentario no tiene sentido si es una ruta de creación ya que por mas opcional que sea el parametro jamás va a existir este id antes de ser creado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay unas cuantas cosas:

**1.**
    ***a-*** *Suponiendo que a la vista del formulario le estás enviando algo como:*

```
public function create()
{
    return view('formulario')->with('marcas', Marca::all());
}
```

***b-*** *El loop de las marcas debería ser algo como esto*

```
<select id="marca" name="marca" class="form-control">
    @foreach($marcas as $mark)
        <option value="$mark->id"> {{'$mark->nombre' }} </option>
    @endforeach  
</select>
```

**2.** En la Ruta eliminá el `/{id?}`  si bien el signo de interrogación hace al parametro opcional la verdad no tiene sentido si estás creando un recurso.
Además creo que tu ruta debería ser un poco mas descriptiva ya que **"nuevo"** no dice mucho.
Podrías colocar la ruta dentro de un grupo.

```
Route::prefix('vehiculo')->group(function () {
    // vehiculo/nuevo
    Route::post('nuevo', 'VehiculoController@agregar_nuevo_vehiculo');
});
```

**3.** tabla `vehiculos`: cambiá la columna `marca` por `marca_id`

*En la migración cambiá la columna `marca` por:*

```
$table->unsignedInteger('marca_id');
$table->foreign('marca_id')->references('id')->on('marcas');
```

*El modelo te quedaría:*

```
class Vehiculo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vehiculos';
    protected $fillable = [
        'matricula', 'marca_id', 'modelo', 'capacidad_carga', 'año_fabricacion', 'color', 'estado',
    ];

    public function marca()
    {   
        return $this->BelongsTo('Marca');
    }
}
```

**4.** En el formulario cambiá
`<select id="marca" name="marca" class="form-control">`
 **por**
`<select id="marca_id" name="marca_id" class="form-control">`

**5.** Ahora en el método `agregar_nuevo_vehiculo()` podrías hacer:

```
public function agregar_nuevo_vehiculo()
{
   $resul = Vehiculo::create(request()->all());
   if ($resul){
       return view ('mensajes.msj_correcto')->with('msj','Nuevo vehiculo incorporado exitosamente');
   }
   else
       return view ('mensajes.msj_rechazado')->with('msj','Hubo un error en al creacion del vehiculo, vuelva a intentarlo, por favor');

}
```

Espero mi explicación te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias @MaruAmallo, estoy intentando implementarlo, tan pronto lo logre te comento como me fue.